# Which version control system should I use for my small personal code files?

Tags: version-control

I have some general scripts that I use and they keep getting modified over time. Right now, I do not use any version control software for them so basically the old files are lost unless I explicitly save them.

I need a good minimal version control system that I can use on a single machine. Which one do you use for such projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Git` or `mercurial` both work great. No server required.

Answer (score 3):

I've used subversion for this in the past.  Mostly this is because I'm in windows, and TortoiseSVN is a dead simple UI for my repo.

For a scenario like yours, which is relatively simple, I'd recommend using either what you're familiar with, or what is easy to use on your platform.

Answer (score 2):

Git is actually really easy to use in such a setting, and it scales just as well to really small repositories with a few commits a month as it does to huge ones with a hundred a day.  Here's how you would set up such a repository:

```
$ cd ~/your-scripts
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Start script repository'
```

Ta-da!

Answer (score 0):

As a hosting solution we make use of http://codesion.com/free_cvs_svn, you will note they also support Git hosting. They also host a bunch of other services that go hand in-in-hand with versioning.

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of the [personal version control](http://www.foldertrack.com) systems. Hers is a short list:

1. [FileHamster](http://www.filehamster.com/)
2. [History Explorer](http://www.exendo.se/)
3. [FolderTrack](http://www.foldertrack.com)
4. [Oops! Backup](http://www.altaro.com)

They are super easy to use and "automatically checkin" when ever you modify your files.

Note: I am the author of FolderTrack and recomend it for software because it can treat a bunch of files as 1 big project. Therefore if you need to revert your project to where it was yesterday, it will revert the 8, 10, or how ever many other files you modified since that time. 
Free code: BOS